# float32_t to uint16_t array

Tags: floating-point, microcontroller

I have some problems on a TI C2000 microcontroller, which does not support uint8_t.

I need to send a float value over CAN and the tx buffer is a uint16_t array of length 8, where each value should be in the range of a uint8_t. What I normally do on a microcontroller supporting uint8_t is using directly memcpy, but here this does not work.

So what I tried is the following:

```
canComVars.txMsgData[0] = addr;

uint16_t tmp[2];
memcpy(&tmp[0], &data_f , sizeof(float32_t)/sizeof(uint16_t)); //data_f --> float32_t
canComVars.txMsgData[1] = (tmp[1]>>8) & 0x00FF;
canComVars.txMsgData[2] = (tmp[1]) & 0x00FF;
canComVars.txMsgData[3] = (tmp[0]>>8) & 0x00FF;
canComVars.txMsgData[4] = (tmp[0]) & 0x00FF;
```

I try to convert the float first in a uint16_t array, where I then can use the bitshift operator. But somehow this is still wrong and gives me wrong values. I also tried to directly use the bitshift on the float value, but this gives a compiler error.

Any ideas, how this can be done?

Comment: Did you try to copy the `float32_t` into a `uint8_t` array, followed by a loop copying each `uint8_t` element into its `uint16_t` target? No need to shift or mask.

Comment: I have no uint8_t array, since the C2000 does not support it. That's why I have such problems

Comment: Is `sizeof(char)==sizeof(uint16_t)` on your microcontroller? (Or `sizeof(float)==2`?)

Comment: But you do have `unsigned char`, don't you? -- Oh, yes, would you mind to [edit] your question and add the sizes of the used data types, please? -- Is `uint32_t` supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

memcpy expects the number of **bytes** to copy. You provided the number of uint16_t elements, which is two. Try this:

```
float32_t data_f=3.14;
unsigned char tmp[4]; 
memcpy(tmp, &data_f, 4);
canComVars.txMsgData[1] = tmp[3];
canComVars.txMsgData[2] = tmp[2];
canComVars.txMsgData[3] = tmp[1];
canComVars.txMsgData[4] = tmp[0];
```